# Название емкости

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До "бутылки" как-то не дотягивает, а "флаконом" обозначаются емкости для хранения летучих веществ.

Comment: Стограммовка, сотка, соточка, — банка.

Answer (score 2):

По форме сосуда и размеру крышки это **банка**. При ссылке на *напиток* можно дипломатично назвать её "*декоративной ёмкостью*" или "*графином*" (как и в случаях запечатывания спиртного в рюмку, стакан, типичный графин и пр. сосуды).

Comment: Невозможно представить, чтобы кто-то сказал — подать банку с бурбоном  или принеси декоративную емкость с бурбоном. А графином тут и не пахнет — и по виду (горло  отсутствует), и по крышке ( здесь она завинчивается, а в графине — нет).  О графинах: Стеклянный или хрустальный сосуд (для воды, вина и т. п.) с узким высоким горлом. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/42242

Comment: Я и не предлагаю произносить такие сочетания (назвал другие предложения для случаев бурбона и пр. напитков), однако по своей конструкции сосуд - именно банка. Графин - чисто _функциональное_ наименование, он может быть любой дизайнерской формы, лишь бы не кувшин. _- Что это за банка под столом? - А в ней вчера был бурбон._

Answer (score 0):

Бутылочка, бутылёк, бутылец, склянка, пузырёк (пузырик, пузырчик), мензурка, фунфырик, сотка (соточка, сотенка; обычно о водке), мерзавчик (около половины стакана; обычно о водке), маленькая, малышка, шкалик (61,5 мл), миньон (для коллекций; 50 мл и менее).
[Флакон (чаще флакончик) — так тоже называют.]

Не рассмотрела, что емкость-то из-под кофе. Извините.
Ну тогда банка, баночка; возможно, склянка, бутылёк.

Comment: Нет, это бурбон.